# Keybindings for multiline edit in VS Code inside a Hyper-V VM

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hyper-v, visual-studio-code, key-binding

The `CTRL+SHIFT+ALT` with `PgUp/PgDn` function to multiline edit in VS Code seems broken inside a Hyper-V VM of Windows 10 (this is when I am inside a `vmconnect.exe` session. I can't think of a particular reason that these keybindings should be disabled.

What causes this, and how can these keybindings be fixed (if there is a valid reason that it doesn't work, I'd be curious what that is, as I see no blocking keybindings from Hyper-V that should cause this)?

Comment: Did you simply check if `cursorColumnSelectPageDown` and `cursorColumnSelectPageUp` keyboard shorcuts are set?